# Bind JS function to checkbox in another script file from razor file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, onchange

I have a partial razor view containing a textbox like -

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.UnitsBought, new { @onchange = "script.updateUnitPrice(this);" } )
```

And it is called from main view and the script is referenced like -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        let script = new UnitAllocationMaintScript();
        script.initialize();
```

And the script is in a different JS file like -

```
var UnitAllocationMaintScript = (function ($, app) {
"use strict";
var updateUnitPrice = function (element) {
....
}
```

But when I change the UnitsBought text box, the error comes up like -

script is undefined.

How should I call the function.

Comment: Load your external js file before $(document).ready(function () {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`script` is defined in the `$(document).ready()` handler function, so is out of scope of the `onchange` attribute which runs under the `window`.

To fix this you could attach the event handler using unobtrusive JS instead of the outdated `on*` attribute. Try this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.UnitsBought, new { @class = "units-bought" } )
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let script = new UnitAllocationMaintScript();
  script.initialize();

  $('.units-bought').change(function() {
    script.updateUnitPrice(this);
  });
});
```

Comment: I cannot use -  $('.units-bought').change(function() {
    script.updateUnitPrice(this);
  });

Comment: Why's that? It's just about the only way your code can work given the location you define `script`.

Comment: Because The units-bought is not the exact ID as the ID is generated at run time because it is a grid item.

Comment: That's irrelevant as I added it as a class...?

Comment: I want the element ID as well based on which I have to perform some calculation. Can I get element ID from class change event?

Comment: Yes - `this.id`, or `$(this).prop('id')`

Answer (score 0):

Use unobtrusive event handlers. In other words, don't use HTML attributes like `onchange`, and instead do:

```
$('#UnitsBought').on('change', function () {
    ...
});
```

Comment: I can't use id selector as the ID is generated at run time.

Comment: That hardly matters. It's not like it's random. Once you know what it is, that's what it will always be. Regardless, you could just as easily use a class or any other valid CSS selector. The point is using the jQuery `on` method rather than hardcoding a function name in an attribute.